# regular expression to select last but one character

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I want MySQL query that will retrieve last but one character in string

EX: hello,RAM,SHIVU,RAJEEV

Output: l,A,V,E

I tried regular expression as follows

> select * from tb_name where fn REGEXP "a$"

this will retrieve last charter as "a", but i want OUTPUT as above.

Comment: `hello`, `RAM`, `SHIVU`, ... are the value of `fn` column? *(separated rows)* Or all of that is at one row as string?

Comment: yes they are value for fn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. And based on your output I have to say you shouldn't write that regex on the `WHERE` clause. Actually you don't need regex. You can use [`SUBSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function to achieve expected result:

```
/* tb_name
+--------+-----------------+
|   fn   | other column(s) |
+--------+-----------------+
| hello  |      ...        |
| RAM    |      ...        |
| SHIVU  |      ...        |
| RAJEEV |      ...        |
+--------+-----------------+
*/

mysql> SELECT SUBSTR(fn, -2, 1) fn FROM tb_name;

/* Output:
+----+-----------------+
| fn | other column(s) |
+----+-----------------+
| l  |      ...        |
| A  |      ...        |
| V  |      ...        |
| E  |      ...        |
+----+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select  left(right(fn, 2),1) from tb_name
```